# cannot execute the ./bin/phpunit file generated by the phpunit-bridge recipe

Tags: symfony, phpunit

after the installation of phpunit-bridge with the `composer require --dev symfoy/phpunit-bridge`, the console send the following information:

```
*Write test cases in the test/folder
*Run php bin/phpunit
```

As I have good manners, I followed the rules and execute:

- `php bin/phpunit` and I get no test but `#!/usr/bin/env php`
- `./bin/phpunit`(as sugested in the [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html)) and I get no test but `#!/usr/bin/env php`

Can anyone explain me what I am doing wrong ?

as asked I add the content of the `PHPUnit.xml.dist` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/6.5/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="config/bootstrap.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="test" force="true" />
        <server name="SHELL_VERBOSITY" value="-1" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>src</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <listeners>
        <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener" />
    </listeners>
</phpunit>
```

and my test folder structure:

```
_ tests  
    |  
    |_ Controller  
        |  
        |_ BlogControllerTest.php
```

EDIT :
I've reinstall everything from scratch and if I don't create the phpunit.xml file, I get the `-help` output of the `phpunit` command (normal behavior I imagine), So I think that the problem comes from my phpunit configuration.

Comment: What do you mean by 'I get no test' ? Show us the output, and your tests directory structure, and phpunit.xml file

Comment: I add test directory structure and the PHPUnit.xml.dist file to the question. Concerning the output this is what I mean by I get no test. my only output is `#!usr/bin/env php`

Comment: Your **php** binary seems ... weird. `#!usr/bin/env php` is just the first line of the phpunit binary. What is `php -v` ?

Comment: `PHP 7.1.12 (cli) (built: Nov 27 2017 15:53:40) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies`

Comment: Can you try to modify the `bin/phpunit` file and replace the first line with `#!/usr/bin/env php` (notice the added slash) ?

Comment: my bad, there was already a "/" if I remove it I get `-bash: ./bin/phpunit: usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory's` it effectively is important (I've modified the question accordingly)

Comment: I still think there is a problem with your php binary. It should not print the first line of the phpunit binary..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it was realy impossible to continue working on my project without runnig some tests. I'm more experienced with php and find the error. There were a typo in my `class` definition

```php
use PHPUnit\Framework\WebTestCase;

class BlogControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function firstTest()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(0,0);
    }
}
```

by changing it to :

```php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
```

which actually exist make everything just fine. So it was just a typo and saddly no error message was triggered. thx for your time and sorry for my mistake.